# Unable to click element in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am trying to click an element inside span but unsuccessful. Here is my code.

Attempt 1 :

```
browser.actions().mouseMove($('.button').click().perform();
```

Attempt 2 :

```
browser.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', elem.getWebElement());
```

Attempt 3 :

```
elm.click();
```

Attempt 4 :

Double click.

When i use any of these above methods , i see the mouse being hovered over the button and the tool tip text is displayed. But the element is not clicked.

Here is my application code :

```
  <button class="button tooltip-bottom ng-star-inserted" data-gs-tooltip=“this will display tooltip“>
      <span class="button-icon"><img class="button-icon" src="sample/pics/icnsvg"></span>
     <div class="button-label">show good</div>
</button>
```

I am struggling to get this work. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Protractor APIs are asynchronous.you need to handle this with promise object. 
you need to resolve the promise here. So that button click should not executed even before the page is ready.

Check with this code:

```
var clkElement = $('.button span');

browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(clkElement), 10000)
.then ( function () {
    clkElement.click();
});
```

It should work. let me know in case you need more help.

Comment: Thank you . Its the same problem again. It finds the element and displays a tool tip text but doesn't click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var elem = element(by.css('.button span'));
return browser.actions().mouseMove(elem).click().perform();
```

Comment: Hi mohanthirteen , thank you for your response. This doesn't seem to work. I have already tried this.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it. I have add

```
 browser.sleep(10000)
```

before clicking on the button.

What surprises me is that i have used

```
browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable
```

and still couldn't get it to work. sleep statement however helped.

Thanks you.